# Whether using Queries in JPA Repositories is proper practice?

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, jpql

I am presently using spring data repository to do a query (multi entity join) and then return a list of POJO objects.  Is this an ok practice?

For example, I have seen code where String has been returned from a query method in a Repository.

```
import java.util.Optional;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.Repository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import com.example.Sample

interface TodoRepository extends Repository<Todo, Long> { 

    @Query("SELECT new com.example.Sample(t.title, b.author) FROM Todo t JOIN t.genre b where t.id = :id") 
    List<Sample> findTitleById(@Param("id") Long id);

    @Query("SELECT t.title FROM Todo t where t.id = :id") 
    List<String> findTitleById(@Param("id") Long id);

    Todo findById(Long id);

    Optional<Todo> findById(Long id);
}
```

So is the first method here ok?
I know it works - but is it bad practice?

Answer (score 1):

The Repository pattern is supposed to help you by autogenerating many of the standard queries from the name of the method, but if you want to create more complex queries you can use `@Query` or write out the method fully.

It's perfectly good practice, that's what the `@Query` annotation is for after all.

Comment: Is it ok that the POJO returned has nothing to do with types specified in the generics (Todo)?

Comment: The generic types don't affect those. They're only for the autogenerated CRUD methods. You can write your own methods returning projections and single column values as you please.

Answer (score 1):

This is fine practice yes. Although i think it's worth noting, if the queries get much longer, eg for reporting / multijoin queries, I prefer to externalise the SQL itself into a separate .sql file and implement the methods and import the sql. This allows for easier editing of the SQL, usually with an IDE plugin, and also generally makes the queries easier to manipulate eg copy and pasting into the real DB to manually test or explain the query for performance reasons. You can still get your results as pojos or lists of pojos by defining the result sets.

Comment: I dont understand this sql file externalization thing. The above queries are JPQL  JPA queries and not plain SQL. Can you give us an example of what you mean.

Comment: Yes I appreciate that. I was just adding a useful note that if queries get large, firstly the @Query solution becomes a bit muddled and harder to read and so implementation of the methods quickly becomes a better solution but that also when queries get very large, as in the case of big reporting queries, moving to plain SQL and externalising it is a good option for the reasons I mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

If you have join in query then it is good practice to go with and makes the queries easier to manipulate.

Below is an other way to get data from database.

**Key and Value pair:**
You can also get data as a Key and Value pair, for that you have to make query as below:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.example.Sample(t.title AS title , b.author AS author) FROM Todo t where t.id = :id")
List<Sample> findTitleById(@Param("id") Long id);
```

And then you will get response like:

```
[
  {
    "title ": "Something",
    "author": "ABC"
  },
  {
    "title ": "Something",
    "author": "XYZ"
  },
  ...
  ...
]
```

But I am not sure about whether we can use JOIN in this scenario or not.